# Extract Number from a String explanation

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, match

I was looking for a way to extract Number/Numbers from a string.
Example:

```
const string = "Monthly Weather Review, Volume 129, Issues 9-12"
```

and i found a solution on this site. The problem is that i don't understand it very well.
Can someone explain me what actually happened in the line below ?

```
let res = string.match(/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g).map(Number); //return [129, 9, -12]
```

Comment: it just matching all number grouped together and looping it to create map

Comment: For more detail, you can paste regex in https://regex101.com/ and understand

Comment: You can simplify `"Monthly Weather Review, Volume 129, Issues 9-12".match(/([+-]?\d+)/g).map(x => Number(x))`

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression:

```
[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

will match substrings which:

- `[+-]?` - May start with a `+` or a `-` (character set, made optional by the following `?`)
- `\d+` - Then, contains one or more digit characters (numbers from 0 to 9)
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - Non-capturing group, made optional by `?`:

  - `\.\d+` - May match a literal `.`, followed by more digit characters

The only part of the pattern that *isn't* used by your input is the decimals part at the end. For an example, in the string

```
foo +12.34
```

it will match `+12.34`.

Regular expression matches extract substrings from a larger string, as an array. The `.map(Number)` uses `Array.prototype.map` to transform all elements of one array into another array - it turns the array of strings into an array of numbers.

Comment: Thank you friend. Can you advise me what is the best way to understand regular expressions ?

Comment: @Rakonjac If you're looking for an introductory tutorial, https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is pretty useful. There are various sites which, given a regex, can automatically describe it or show the control flow, like regex101 and debuggex.com

Answer (score 0):

For starters `.match(regex)` is a method on the `String` prototype that given a regular expression, will execute it and return to you the results or `null` if there aren't any matches. See this for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

For the regular expression, `/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g`:

- `[+-]?` match optionally a + or -
- `\d+` match one or more numerical digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` non-capturing group of `.` followed by digits (you're getting the decimal values here). This is optional with the `?`. It looks like they only want integers here.
- `/g` - `g` for global. all matches returned.

**More info on regular expressions**: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

`.map(Number)` will iterate over each string item in the matches array (all matches are strings because that is what the first thing was) and coerce to number by using the `Number()` function.

**More info on `Number`**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

**More info on `.map`**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map